# The method is there, but I cannot use it?

Tags: php

`Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object` on

```
pr($transaction->invoice->get());
```

I am getting a weird message. I know for sure the method is there, and is available to use, and even double checked before using it. What's wrong here?

```
pr(get_class_methods($transaction->invoice));
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => get
    [2] => __toString
    [3] => getHref
    [4] => setHref
    [5] => _get
)
```

**Update:**

`var_dump(is_object($transaction->invoice));` evaluated as `bool(true)`

None  of the methods work. I'm so confused! I think this is one of those edge cases. I'm using Recurly library.

**Update**

Looks like some objects coming back were un-instantiating themselves. That's weird. I didn't know PHP does this.

Comment: Did you try doing it in two lines? `$inv = $transaction->invoice;` and then `$inv->get();`?

Comment: @MarkEirich `$inv = $transaction->invoice;` works fine, but the `get()` blows up.

Comment: Does the error message say what file and line the error is on? And are you absolutely sure that this error message refers to the line shown above and not some line in the Recurly library?

Comment: Does `$transaction->invoice->getHref()` work? Do you get anything for `$transaction->invoice->invoice_number`?

Comment: I honestly don't see anything in the docs or in the code to indicate that you could call `$transaction->invoice->get()` and get anything useful. There is a get() function, but it is as static function, to be used like this: `$invoice = Recurly_Invoice::get('1005');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you experience here is **Magic**. As Magic is so hard to understand, it's even harder to debug. Expect a large chunk of that Recurly PHP library to be based on Magic.

> Looks like some objects coming back were un-instantiating themselves. That's weird. I didn't know PHP does this.

It's not PHP, but the library. It makes use of [magic getters and setters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and other magic stuff for the properties. They must have been driven by some wizard being so much in love with magic. Don't you feel enchanted yet?

Best way to get above the Magic is that you install yourself a step debugger like **Xdebug** and then set a breakpoint and inspect the values directly. All common PHP IDEs have support for [xdebug remote debugging](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote) (even this is called remote debugging, it works on your local development machine, too).

Comment: I will definitely look into this. Thanks for the reply!